# Get SIM info in Windows 7 netbook

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sim-card

I am working on a project using C# and Windows Forms. I want to get information about the SIM  card which is placed on a Dell Latitude 2110 Netbook with Windows 7 installed. Any ideas of how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the "Cellular module" in the hardware manager.

See if there is a serial port associated with it. If there is one, there are tons of examples online. If not, you may have to download some sort of SDK from the manufacturer's website (this will most likely be the manufacturer of the actual module, not Dell).

Please provide more information so you can get a better answer...

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I searched in netboook's web page (http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/product/latitude-2120) without finding something useful. The only useful stuff I've managed to find is here: http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx but it is not well documented (at least in the community edition) and I have not managed to make it work so far...

Comment: What I meant in my first line was have a look at the `Computer Management->Hardware` and see if there is a section called `Ports (COM & LPT)` (or something in the lines of that). If you have COM port(s), note the number(s) (e.g. `COM3`) then open a terminal application (`putty` and `teraterm` are good ones) and open the port you noted earlier. Try to send some `AT` commands (Google: "cellular modem at commands" or "gsm modem at commands"). See if you get any response. If you get anything back, keep searching Google and you'll find the right AT commands to accomplish what you need.